# Click and view more pages with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**Problem**
I need to go into all the top user profile in this [page](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663) using Selenium.
The Top users profile are located in the right of the page.

**What i've done**

```
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    user_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[contains(@class,"W-100 Bc-c")]/tbody/tr')
    for single_user in user_list:
        single_user.find_element_by_xpath('.//td/a').click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

But I get this error message:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable
>   at point (865, 685). Other element would receive the click:

```
<div id="MouseoverMask" class="End-0 Start-0 T-0 B-0"></div>
```

**Info**
Python 2.7.10
Selenium 2.48
Pycharm

**EDIT+**

I try to make a print of the name and it works:

```
   print(str( single_user.find_element_by_xpath('.//td/a').text ) )
```

But the click() no.

Comment: So what happens if you run that? What is the error?

Comment: your xpath looks OK, so where is the issue?

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (865, 685). Other element would receive the click: <div id="MouseoverMask" class="End-0 Start-0 T-0 B-0"></div>

Comment: If you look at the HTML Selenium is seeing, it's completely blank (or it is for me) - so possibly Yahoo is taking measures against scraping.

Comment: @user3468054 mhhh i using selenium in order to take other things like url of the questions and it works. However if you look with debug the user_list will be created and the for can be executed for any single_user if you add a print("example") instead of the .click()

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi  i edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any error at my end but after first click web elements are ***changed*** so you will not get the next web element as captured earlier in xpath. By the way try below code-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663')
user_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[contains(@class,"W-100 Bc-c")]/tbody/tr')
lnks = [i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td/a').get_attribute('href') for i in user_list]
for single_user in lnks:
    driver.get(single_user)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you sure that the object you get is the right one, often the problem is:

- The object is not visible
- Page was not fully loaded when you try to click on the object.

So just take a look on the Wait method provided by Selenium and be sure your object is visible

In order to wait an element to be clickable :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid')))
```

In your case, you can try to find each element with the id you got and click on it :

```
self.driver.get(response.url)
user_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[contains(@class,"W-100 Bc-c")]/tbody/tr')
for single_user in user_list:
    id = single_user.find_element_by_xpath('.//td/a').get_attribute("id")
    self.driver.find_elements_by_id(id).click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Yes object is visibile and before i wait about 5 sec.

Comment: Did you try to wait as the form i just added in my post?

Comment: With wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'ya-leader-board')))

Comment: Element is not clickable at point (871, 693). Other element would receive the click: <div id="MouseoverMask" class="End-0 Start-0 T-0 B-0"></div>

Comment: Can you test my last edit (i'm not sure about syntax to get the id attribut)